# handle toolbar appearance individually on different Activities

Tags: android, android-toolbar

i have 2 Activities say activity1 and activity2

and in both activities i added toolbar

**CODES**

*Activity1*:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTrendingActivity"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

*activity2*

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTagDetailActivity"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="toolbar2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ToolbarTagDetailActivity_title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

as you can see both toolbars have an Unique id

i'm making  `activity2's` toolbar transparent which is working fine but when i'm switching from `activity2` to `activity1` my `activity1's` toolbar is also transparent

for getting it back i'm doing this  on activity1:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
  toolbarBackground = toolbar.getBackground(); 
}


    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(toolbarBackground);
    } else {
        toolbar.setBackground(toolbarBackground);
    }

}
```

but the above code is not doing anything i also tried to set the background color manually like this 
[image]

but its not  returning the correct color , my primaryColor is blue but now toolbar's background  is purple color

anyone can guide me how can i fix this ??

EDIT

toolbarStyle :

```
    <style name="ToolBarStyle"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

*Default toolbar (desired Toolbar)*

[image]

*current toolbar (after switching back from activity2)*

[image]

Comment: check your ToolBarStyle in style.xml file..

Comment: well i removed the them for toolbar of activity1 still toolbar is transparent @tk1505

Comment: can you share your **ToolBarStyle** style file?

Comment: @AmanGupta please check the updated question

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You did not need to use this,

```
toolbarBackground = toolbar.getBackground();
```

and no need to do something in onResume().

Simply use set the

```
toolbar.setBackgroundResource(R.color.price_color);
```

in your activity after this block of code in onCreate()

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And if you are getting error in

`toolbar.setBackgroundColor(R.color.price_color);`

use ***ContextCompat.getColor*** method for that

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary_color));
```

Comment: man i appreciate your effort but i think you should read my question o more time , my toolbar is totally normal on first launch but once I'm switching between activity's (from activity1 to activity2) then i'm having this problem and in my activity2 i'm making my toolbar transparent

Comment: I read your ques properly, man you didn't need to do anything in onResume(). As @Yasin Kaçmaz said, why you changing toolbar ?, you must have 2 different toolbar in your 2 different activities.

Comment: So you can simply change the color of your toolbar in onCreate() method of your both the activities.

Comment: And you have used simply the activity not the fragment. So why are u doing this alot of things. I didn' t get it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code when changing `Toolbar` color :

```
 public static void changeToolbarColor(ActionBar actionBar,int color){
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
}
```

When using : `changeToolbarColor(getSupportActionBar(),color);`

Make sure you did this in `onCreate` :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: i tried  your suggestion man still its in purple color @yasin

Comment: @remyboys can you tell me what is your color , how you passing color attribute to method ?

Comment: here you go my color values `<color name="colorPrimary">#03A9F4</color>`
    `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0288d1</color>`

Comment: my code working, i am using it in my application maybe can you add more code and i will look ?

Answer (score 1):

it turns out the that toolbar of activity1 is using the alpha of toolbar2 (from activity2) because i'm changing it on activity2 (for making toolbar transparent ) so changing alpha did the Job :

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    toolbarBackground =  toolbar.getBackground();
    toolbarBackground.setAlpha(255);

    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(toolbarBackground);
    } else {
        toolbar.setBackground(toolbarBackground);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you changing toolbar ?, you must have 2 different toolbar in your 2 different activities

Comment: i already have two separate toolbar's in separate xmls @YasinKaçmaz `android:id="@+id/toolbarTagDetailActivity"`  ,  `android:id="@+id/toolbarTrendingActivity"`

Comment: @so why you changing your toolbar color in `onResume` i didnt get that point?

Comment: because somehow my activity1 is setting its  toolbar's alpha to `x` (taken by activity2)

Comment: i'm also confused if i have separate Toolbars then why is this happening

Comment: if you dont feel lazy can you send any video because i have an app and i am able to change color programmatically in any time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118252/discussion-between-remy-boys-and-yasin-kacmaz).